# crypt error for file link

Tags: crypt

im trying to create a file sharing website but im a begginer at php 
this is the string

```
$_file['file_short_url']        = substr( preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", '', crypt( $_file['file_key'] ) ), 0, 5 );
```

and it gives me this error `Notice: crypt(): No salt parameter was specified. You must use a randomly generated salt and a strong hash function to produce a secure hash`
idk what im doing wrong can someone help me pls
thank you

Comment: It is ok, it is just notice about `salt` parameter that you don't provide to `crypt` function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a salt, but if you want to avoid the notice:

$_file['file_short_url'] 
= substr(
    preg_replace(
        "/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", 
        crypt( $_file['file_key'], 'my_secret_salt')
    ), 
  0, 
  5
);

What are you doing here?  Why are you preg_replacing?

Comment: That idea isn't good, as the salt is included in the output of crypt(). The question "What are you doing here?" is very appropriate...

Comment: That idea might not be good, but I think that it answers his question, while at the same time communicating that perhaps (given that we don't know what his ultimate goal is) there is a better way to achieve what it seems like he's doing.